# React-Table V7 useSortBy Hook not working properly

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Using react-table V7 useSortBy hook's `toggleSortBy` function toggles ascending first then descending and then on third toggle instead of setting `isSortedDesc` to false, it sets `isSorted` to false.

I want to keep toggling between `true` and `false` values till a different header is clicked.

check this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/sorting?file=/src/App.js) for reference of the issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use of `toggleSortBy` function on the table header from column property and call it on `onClick` event

```
<th 
      {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())} 
      onClick={() => column.toggleSortBy(!column.isSortedDesc)}
>
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-frog-evtjy)